# Backbone collection.reset adds one incorrect model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have a collection which is filtered through a search box. When a search/filter is performed, I get a result which is a collection. This collection is correct and contains the expected models from the search. When I use `collection.reset(result)` it adds a backbone collection which contains one model which has nothing to do with the result collection, nor does it contain anything but the standard collection backbone stuff.

The Collection

```
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Product,
    url : '',

    search : function(letters){

        if(letters == "") return this;

        var pattern = new RegExp(letters,"gi");
        return new Products((this.filter(function(data) {
            return pattern.test(data.get("title"));
        })));
    }

});
```

From the view:

```
    search : function (ev){
        var results = products.search($("#search").val());
        console.log("result");
        console.log(results);
        this.collection.reset(results);
        console.log("altered collection");
        console.log(this.collection);
    }
```

And an image showing what it contains at the different points of logging:
[image]

Again the filtered collection (after result) is 100% correct and what I expect it to be. The state of this.collection prior reset, is also correct. The only thing I do is this.collection.reset(result); and log this.collection again. I listen to the `'reset'` event, and when it fires there is obviously no models to render and I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like `results` is a Products collection. `collection.reset()` expects an array of models, not a collection.

Try `this.collection.reset(results.models);`

Comment: Interesting, that worked. I swear I tried that yesterday as well (was my first thought to be honest), but I guess it was late. Thanks anywho.